# SmtpClient is not returning any exception but the mail is not sent, why?

Tags: c#, smtp

I am using SmtpClient() to send mail.The problem is that, it is not returning any kind of exception while sending mail but the mail is not sent. Where might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes emails from your application end up in the Junk folder or take some time before they get delivered. So try waiting for 10-15 minutes.

You may also try changing the smtp server credentials and use some other server like Gmail.